# Getting "java.lang.VerifyError: Instruction type does not match stack map" with testng 6.1.1 and surefire version 2.12

Tags: java, maven, testng

I tried running the codebase using jdk version 1.7 with the following configurations in pom.xml :

```
<plugins>
                        <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                                <version>3.1</version>
                                <configuration>
                                        <source>1.7</source>
                                        <target>1.7</target>
                                </configuration>
                        </plugin>

                        <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                                <version>3.0-beta-2</version>
                                <configuration>
                                        <reportPlugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>2.5</version>
                        </plugin>
                                        </reportPlugins>
                                </configuration>
                        </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12</version>
                <configuration>
                        <argLine>-Xmx1024m</argLine>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>
```

And following testng version :

```
<dependency>
              <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
              <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
              <version>6.1.1</version>
              <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

However, I am facing the following error while building the code( although the build is success) :

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Instruction type does not match stack map 

at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 450         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 451         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 452         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 453         at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
 454         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:525)
 455         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:202)
 456         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:130)
 457         at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeBeforeClassMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:173)
 458         at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:105)
 459         at org.testng.TestRunner.runWorkers(TestRunner.java:1178)
 460         at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:757)
 461         at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:608)
 462         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
 463         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
 464         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
 465         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
 466         at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
 467         at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
 468         at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1158)
 469         at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1083)
 470         at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:999)
 471         at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:76)
 472         at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.executeMulti(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:161)
 473         at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.execute(TestNGDirectoryTestSuite.java:101)
 474         at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:115)
 475         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 476         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
 477         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 478         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
 479         at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
 480         at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
 481         at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
 482         at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:103)
 483         at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:74)
```

I found that the issue was maybe because of the testng not supporting parallel operations : https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/pull/190

On changing the maven-surefire version to 3.0.0-M4 , I am getting the following error :

```
WARNING: Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:

1) No implementation for org.codehaus.plexus.languages.java.jpms.LocationManager was bound.
  while locating org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$3.get(InjectorImpl.java:974)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1000)
    at org.sonatype.guice.bean.reflect.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:84)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:52)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:100)
    at org.sonatype.guice.plexus.lifecycles.PlexusLifecycleManager.onProvision(PlexusLifecycleManager.java:138)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:108)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:55)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$3$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:965)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1011)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$3.get(InjectorImpl.java:961)
    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
    at org.sonatype.guice.bean.locators.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:83)
    at org.sonatype.guice.plexus.locators.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:253)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:245)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:455)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:92)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
```

I have tried using maven-compiler version 3.6.0, 3.3.9, 3.1 , but it doesn't work. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you make a complete working project on Github ...With which JDK are you running? And why are you using such ancient versions of maven-site-plugin ? Why using cobertura?

Comment: Actually it is a legacy code that I am making changes to. Sorry cant share the entire codebase. But ya, I am using jdk 1.7.

Comment: Please add Maven version you are using `mvn --version` ...

Comment: Using Apache Maven 3.0.4

Comment: Really such an old version...3.0.4 contains a large number bugs...please upgrade to most recent versions...

Comment: So I upgraded the maven version to 3.3.9, but I still get the VerifyError.

Comment: I wrote upgrade to the most recent which is 3.6.3 furthermore upgrade maven-surefire also to the most recent versions etc. Best would be having a github repo where we could take a look into ...